# Fill ComboBox Items in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I Have two classes like these:

```
public class Instance
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Identity of index
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Items within this group.
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, ItemRow> Items;

    public Instance()
    {
        //Items = new Dictionary<string, ItemRow>();
        Items = new Dictionary<string, ItemRow>();
    }
}

public class GroupMemory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the OPC group
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Scan rate for this group.
    /// </summary>
    public string ScanRate { get; set; }
    /// <summary> 
    /// Number of instances for this group.
    /// </summary>
    public int CountOfInstances { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instances within this group.
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<int, Instance> Instances;
    /// <summary>
    /// Items within this group.
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<string, ItemRow> Items;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor of GroupMemory class.
    /// </summary>
    public GroupMemory()
    {
        Items = new Dictionary<string, ItemRow>();
        Instances = new Dictionary<int, Instance>();
    }
}
```

I have a listview that i bind GroupMemory object in each item of listview. Last column of listview is a ComboBox that i need to bind Id of each instances of a groupmemory in it. for example if each group memory contains two instances and instances have Id=1 and Id=2, i want to show 1 and 2 in combobox as its items. how can i write xaml code for combobox or its code behinde?

here is my xaml code for listview

```
<ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}, Converter={StaticResource starWidthConverter}}"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Scan Rate" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ScanRate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Instances" Width="60" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CountOfInstances}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Index" Width="100">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Width="50" ItemsSource="{Binding Instances}" SelectedValue="{Binding Id}" DisplayMemberPath="Id"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

Comment: How does your `ListView` look at the moment?

Comment: @dkozl now all the column have value, but combobox columns do not have item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `DataContext` of the ComboBox is an instance of `GroupMemory` class, you can try to bind ComboBox's `ItemsSource` to `Instances.Values` property and set `DisplayMemberPath` to display `Id` of each `Instance` :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Instances.Values}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Id"
          SelectedValuePath="Id"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i set it as your code but it does not work. i put my xaml code in main post

Comment: Binding only work with public *properties*. Try to change definition of `Instances` to be a property *instead* of *field* : `public Dictionary<int, Instance> Instances { get; set; }`

Comment: Dear @har07  i change my definition to public properties like your given code. but it does not work anymore :(

Comment: Run your app in debug mode and see output window to find out if any related binding error there..

Answer (score 3):

Your `Instances` is declared as a field and it's not a valid [binding source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643(v=vs.110).aspx). You should convert it to a property if you want to bind to it. Change declaration to:

```
public Dictionary<int, Instance> Instances { get; set; }
```

and then, because it's a `Dictionaty<K, V>`, and each item is of a `KeyValuePair<K, V>` type where `Key` is your `int` and `Value` is your `Instance` try changing `DisplayMemberPath` to `Value.Id`

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Instances}" DisplayMemberPath="Value.Id"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you bind the itemsource to the Instances property, you could then bind the DisplayMember and/or valuemember to Key or Value.

Its relatively simple

Instances is a KeyValuePair, you will need to bind to Value.Id

However i also noticed that neither of your classes implement INotifyPropertyChanged. You will need to implement this as this is how the Binding knows your values have been updated.

You may also need to check out the ObservableDictionary if you're stuck on using a dictionary. http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/

Comment: the Instances property is a KeyValuePair. You will need to bind to Value.Id, That should make it work

Comment: thanks @Dale. i change my dictionary to a list and it works properly. thanks for your advice dear friend